# How to access the options of the Label Properties dialog in QGIS2.14.2?

Tags: qgis, labeling

The Change Label tool has a Label Properties dialog but the options are greyed out.

How to access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your layer has to be in edit mode to enable the tool.

All the parameters in the Change Label box are data defined fields, so you need to have fields corresponding in your attribute table.

After creating the new fields in the attribute table, go to the proprieties dialog, and set up the fields you want access.

For exemple, for the X coordinate :

[image]

The "X coordinate" of the Change Label box is now editable.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I already have x & y fields in another layer. So I must to setup fields for every option, right? Where I can read about it?

Comment: Yes, you have to add fiels and setup every option you want customize individually (no need for global options for the layer). Alternatively, it can often be better to use expression insteed of direct field. It's true the qgis documentation is lacking details on this functionality. You can click on "Decription..." on the pop-up menu appearing when you setup data defined field for few informations about expected values.